# Where is the cache for the MySQL caching_sha2_password auth plugin stored?

Tags: mysql, authentication, mysql-8.0

Where is the cache for the new default authentication plugin *caching_sha2_password* in MySQL 8 stored? I want to know for future reference how to clear it in case I ever run into any problems using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'when there exists a cached copy of the password hash in memory' ([ref](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/)).

So its all in memory.

[FLUSH PRIVILEGES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html#caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication-cache-operation) can clear it

Answer (score -1):

- Open MySQL from System Preferences > Initialize Database >
- Type your new password.
- Choose 'Use legacy password'
- Start the Server again.
- Now connect the MySQL Workbench

Please read full Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Comment: Is this an answer to how to clear the cache used by the caching_sha2_password plugin or how to gain access while dealing with the popular incompatibility issue with MySQL 8 and the caching_sha2_password plugin?